# Tic Tac Toe Module in Rust: Implementing "new"

Tags: beginner, rust, tic-tac-toe

## Intro

In order to get familiar with and improve my Rust skills I coded Tic-Tac-Toe. I want to write good Rust code, any feedback regarding why my code isn't in a Rust style or improvements that could be made would be very helpful.

### Question

Is there a better way to implement my "new" method for the Ttt struct? I don't particularly like manually passing the array `['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']` to both `board` and `options: Ttt::create_options()`, but I haven't seen a way around doing it like that.

## Code

#### lib.rs

```
pub mod tictactoe {
    use std::collections::HashMap;
    use std::io;

    const BOARD_SIZE: usize = 9;
    const P1: char = 'X';
    const P2: char = 'O';
    pub struct Ttt {
        pub board: [char; BOARD_SIZE],
        pub options: HashMap<usize, char>,
        pub active_player: char,
        pub game_over: bool,
        pub winner: char,
    }

    impl Ttt {
        fn create_options(board: [char; BOARD_SIZE]) -> HashMap<usize, char> {
            let mut options = HashMap::new();
            for space in 0..board.len() {
                options.insert(space, board[space]);
            }

            return options;
        }

        // I feel like this needs improvement
        pub fn new() -> Ttt {
            Ttt {
                board: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
                options: Ttt::create_options(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']),
                active_player: P1,
                game_over: false,
                winner: ' ',
            }
        }

        pub fn play(&mut self) -> char {
            while !self.game_over {
                self.print_board();

                let pick = self.get_input();
                self.options.remove(&pick);
                self.board[pick] = self.active_player;

                self.game_over = self.is_game_over();

                if self.game_over {
                    self.winner = self.active_player;
                } else {
                    self.switch_player();
                }
            }

            self.print_board();
            println!("\n{} is the winner!", self.winner);
            return self.winner;
        }

        pub fn is_game_over(&self) -> bool {
            if self.options.len() < 1 {
                println!("It's a tie!");
                return true;
            }
            if self.board[0] == self.board[1] && self.board[0] == self.board[2] {
                println!("Top row win!");
                return true;
            }
            if self.board[3] == self.board[4] && self.board[3] == self.board[5] {
                println!("Middle row win!");
                return true;
            }
            if self.board[6] == self.board[7] && self.board[6] == self.board[8] {
                println!("Bottom row win!");
                return true;
            }
            if self.board[0] == self.board[3] && self.board[0] == self.board[6] {
                println!("Left column win!");
                return true;
            }
            if self.board[1] == self.board[4] && self.board[1] == self.board[7] {
                println!("Center column win!");
                return true;
            }
            if self.board[2] == self.board[5] && self.board[2] == self.board[8] {
                println!("Right column win!");
                return true;
            }
            if self.board[0] == self.board[4] && self.board[0] == self.board[8] {
                println!("Backslash win!");
                return true;
            }
            if self.board[2] == self.board[4] && self.board[2] == self.board[6] {
                println!("Forwardslash win!");
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        pub fn switch_player(&mut self) {
            if self.active_player == P1 {
                self.active_player = P2;
            } else {
                self.active_player = P1;
            }
        }

        pub fn print_board(&self) {
            println!(
                " {} | {} | {} ",
                self.board[0], self.board[1], self.board[2]
            );
            println!("-----------");
            println!(
                " {} | {} | {} ",
                self.board[3], self.board[4], self.board[5]
            );
            println!("-----------");
            println!(
                " {} | {} | {} ",
                self.board[6], self.board[7], self.board[8]
            );
        }

        pub fn get_options(&self) -> &HashMap<usize, char> {
            return &self.options;
        }

        pub fn get_input_ML(&self, choice: usize) -> usize {
            return choice;
        }

        pub fn get_input(&self) -> usize {
            println!("Choose a selection from the grid.");
            loop {
                let mut coord = String::new();
                io::stdin()
                    .read_line(&mut coord)
                    .expect("Failed to read line");
                let coord: usize = match coord.trim().parse() {
                    Ok(num) => num,
                    Err(_) => {
                        println!("Please enter a valid selection.");
                        continue;
                    }
                };
                if !self.options.contains_key(&coord) {
                    println!("Please enter a valid selection.");
                    continue;
                }
                return coord;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### main.rs

```
use ttt::tictactoe::Ttt;

fn main() {
    let mut g = Ttt::new();
    g.play();
}
```

#### Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "ttt"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

Any feedback is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it in a local value for brevity. That's it.

```rust
pub fn new() -> Ttt {
    let board = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'];
    Ttt {
        board,
        options: Ttt::create_options(board),
        active_player: P1,
        game_over: false,
        winner: ' ',
    }
}
```

Edit: and this looks fine to me, I'm not sure what kind of improvement you're looking for. I can't see any potential for clear improvement here. You may intialize `options` to an empty HashMap and update it after you construct the `Ttt`. That way, you wouldn't pass anything explicitly.

You may determine whether the game is a tie earlier, when there is one vacant square rather than with no remaining vacant squares. I leave that as a potential exercise for you.

I feel like you should abandon this implementation of `options` and use `board` as the only source of info about the board.

I would do `vacant_coords`.

```rust
fn vacant_coords(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=usize> + '_ {
    self.board.iter().enumerate().filter_map(|(i, &ch)| {
        if ch == P1 || ch == P2 {
            None
        } else {
            Some(i)
        }
    })
}
```

Use that to check for number of vacant coords

```rust
if self.vacant_coords().count() == 0 {
    println!("It's a tie!");
    return true;
}
```

Use that to check whether input is a vacant coord

```rust
if !self.vacant_coords().find(|&i| i == coord).is_some() {
    println!("Please enter a valid selection.");
    continue;
}
```